# Request body field processing in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring base web application where, we have a few RestControllers and some Request DTO classes. Request DTO contains a token field which needs some validation. So I used spring validators to validate that. After validation, we want to send that field to an external system using another REST API (Just for some kind of analytics logging). The same field is repeated in multiple DTO objects and their controllers. So, I am easily able to define annotations for validators and reuse them across the DTOs. But I am not sure how to process that field after validation succeeds (i.e. call analytics API to consume that field post validation), without mixing it with the core logic of controllers.

Approaches I could think of:

1. Implement a filter/interceptor and process the field there. But then
   there is a limitation that request body can be read only once so I
   need to use some alternate ways by creating request wrappers.
2. Repeat the logic in every controller and it is very error prone as for
   every new controller we need to remember to write that code.

But non of these approaches look cleaner. Can someone recommend a better way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseController` and implement the method there. Extend this `BaseController` wherever you need this logging service. Like below.

**BaseController.java**

```
class BaseController {
protected void remoteLogging(String name,String token) {
//Calling the remote log services}
}
```

**AppController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("register")
public class LeaseController extends BaseController {

@PostMapping("new")
public String new(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registration") Registration registration,BindingResult result){ 
if(rest.hasErrors(){
remoteLogging("name","token");
}
}
```

Comment: But then this logic need to be there with every controller and every method which is error prone as I mentioned in point #2 above.

Comment: Only the call will there inside the controllers, the actual logic resides inside Basecontroller only. Do you think even the call will contains error? Also if you put this globally even for non necessary calls it will get invoked.